# Pass additional parameters to django_table2 TemplateColumn

Tags: django-tables2

In my django project I have a lot of tables which return models. The last column is mostly an Action-Column where users may edit or delete an instance. How do I proceed if I want to pass additional arguments to TemplateColumn if in some tables I want an edit and delete button and in other tables I only need an edit and info button? I want to use the same template.html but with conditions in it. Here what I have in Table:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from select_tool.models import DefactoCapability

class DefactoCapabilityTable(tables.Table):

    my_column = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name='Actions', template_name='core/actionColumnTable.html')

    class Meta:
         model = DefactoCapability
         template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
         attrs = {'class': 'table table-xss table-hover'}
         exclude = ( 'body', )
         orderable = False
```

And how do I check perms on the actions in order to display the button or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [`TemplateColumn` docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn)

> A Template object is created [...] and rendered with a context containing:
>
> - `record` – data record for the current row
> - `value` – value from record that corresponds to the current column
> - `default` – appropriate default value to use as fallback
> - `row_counter` – The number of the row this cell is being rendered in.
> - any context variables passed using the `extra_context` argument to `TemplateColumn`.

So you could do something like this:

```
my_column = tables.TemplateColumn(
    template_name='core/actionColumnTable.html',
    extra_context={
        'edit_button': True,
    }
)
```

The context also contains the complete context of the template from where `{% render_table %}` is called. So if you have `'django.template.context_processors.request'` in your `context_processors`, you can access the current user using `{{ request.user }}`.